# Android Firebase Fetch Data Of Every User

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

For example, there are 2 main nodes in my database (there can be more). The parent node is the user's authentication id and inside it
there is some detail as you can see.
I am trying to do that if any user login all other user's data populated on his activity
but I really don't know how to start because every user has its own authentication id and there are sub-nodes also like map location and image
How can I fetch every user's detail to the activity?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it's right approach or not, but you can create another node with email ids, where you can save thread id for each email and from there you can get the specific node and get data related to that user.

Comment: @rookieDeveloper sir could not understand your point

Comment: If I understand correct you need to populate your activity with data from all users except for the one that signed in?

Comment: @Napster yes sir. But  I really don't know how to begin

Comment: Why don't you get the data from the `fbuserinfo` node which would be a map of user Ids against your users and iterate through that?

Comment: Sir can you please share some code snippet of iteration in map

Comment: Sure, can you show me what the map location and image objects are?

Comment: I just updated my firebase node picture

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is that get the data from the `fbuserinfo` node using an event listener like this and iterate through the data. Here `User.class` is the class for the User model that you have created

```
DatabaseReference userDataReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("fbuserinfo");

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          User user = ds.getValue(User.class);
          Log.d("User", user);
        }
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){
      Log.d(TAG, "Error fetching user data - " + databaseError.getMessage());
    }
  }
userDataReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

And then if you want to display the data, you can do it in the for loop and have an if condition to check if the user is not equal to the current one

Comment: Ok sir let me test this

Comment: I using Recyclerview to bring data to activity.Should I write this snippet in onBindViewHolder function which is inside in Adapter class?

Comment: No what you would do is that get all the data in an `ArrayList` and then pass it to your `RecyclerView` adapter

Comment: Ok now on this line "User user = ds.getValue(User.class);"
It is showing me this error
"Exception com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String"

Comment: That means there is something wrong in your `User.class` model and it doesn't reflect your actual object

Answer (score 0):

Using the following example you'll be able to log the `name` of all users from your database.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference fbRef = rootRef.child("Users").child("fbusersinfo");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
fbRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
Ahmend Abbas
mahanoor 4
```

If you need also the other properties, you can get them in the same manner.